# Need help returning arbitrary content from a shape method in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I have implemented a shape method as described in [Need help implementing an Orchard CMS Shape Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29170241/need-help-implementing-an-orchard-cms-shape-method), but now I am running into a problem when I try to grab and return content using a query.

The shape method works, but if I add the following line, it then produces an error in looking for a view:

```
var items = _contentManager.Query<TitlePart, TitlePartRecord>().Where(t => t.Title.Contains("Orchard"));
```

I can make the error go away by creating the view that it is looking for, but then that overrides the text I am trying to return in the shape method.

How would I grab a content item from Orchard and return text from the item(s) using my shape method, as well as circumventing the view error that is being generated?

I have added the necessary Usings and reference to IContentManager, etc.

**Update**

The error I am getting is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here is the full stack trace: http://pastebin.com/fB8bYtML

Comment: Please include the error that is generated

Comment: Sorry about that and for the delay -- my error has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Content Query does not support String.Contains method (Content Query uses NHibernate.Linq.Query).
You can use Hql Query instead

```
var items = _contentManager.HqlQuery().Where(
    a => a.ContentPartRecord<TitlePartRecord>(),
    p => p.Like("Title", "Orchard", Orchard.ContentManagement.HqlMatchMode.Anywhere));
```

Comment: Keep in mind that LIKE queries tend to be really slow.

Comment: This appears to give me the same error I described above.

Comment: Do you have assignment operator _contentManager = contentManager in controller constructor? Have you tried to use HqlQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are missing the .List() at the end of the query. Right now I think you are returning an IQueryable object to give you the ability to add more filters to the query. You need to add the .List() to the end of the query to execute the query at the database and return an IEnumerable.

```
var items = _contentManager.Query<TitlePart, TitlePartRecord>().Where(t => t.Title.Contains("Orchard")).List();
```